# Parsing Ruby var in JSON

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to parse my **@products** results, but I get the error:

```
VM1583:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at builder:114
```

**Controller**

```
  def builder
    @products = Product.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'builder' }
        format.json
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<script>
    var products = JSON.parse('<%= @products.to_json %>');
    console.log(products);
</script>
```

¿Any idea of what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the JSON output otherwise it's impossible to debug. And why would you do `to_json` to then just parse it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that `@products.to_json` produces a string and `<%= ... %>` will escape any [special HTML characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents).

Let's have a look at an example:

```rb
# assume the @products.to_json result is:
json = '[{"name": "a"}]'
```

This will result in the following:

```js
const json = '<%= json %>';
const json = '[{&quot;name&quot;: &quot;a&quot;}]';
```

To solve this you should use [`escape_javascript`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) or its alias [`j`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j) to mark the `json` string as HTML safe and escape special characters within JavaScript string context:

```js
const json = '<%= j json %>';
const json = '[{\"name\": \"a\"}]';
```

This result can then be parsed as using the JavaScript `JSON.parse(...)`. However since JSON can also be parsed as JavaScript you could also assign it directly to a variable using [`raw`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) or [`<%== ... %>`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#output-safety) (notice the `==` instead of `=`). This will output the string without modifying or escaping anything.

```js
const products = <%= raw json %>;
const products = <%== json %>;
const products = [{"name": "a"}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding `html_safe` like this:

```
<script>
    var products = JSON.parse('<%= @products.to_json.html_safe %>');
    console.log(products);
</script>
```

Cheers

Comment: Be careful with this solution it isn't completely safe. Let's say the the there is a product with a title/name that contains a `'` character. This will now end string context and the characters after it will be interpreted as JavaScript. Use the [`escape_javascript`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) (or its alias [`j`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j)) to mark the string as both HTML safe and escape special characters within string context.

Comment: ^ `var products = JSON.parse('<%= j @products.to_json %>');` Alternatively since JSON can be parsed as JavaScript you could also do `var products = <%= raw @products.to_json %>;`

Comment: Using JSON.parse is redundant